# Permutation matching function

Tags: function, statistics, permutation, matching

I am trying to create a function, basically regarding coats and people. If a cloakroom randomly mixing up coats, on average how many people will end up with there own coat. With k amount of people. Here is my function, however when I call the function it isn't returning my answer :

```
Umbrella=function(k)
m=rep(0,10000)
for (i in 1:10000){
Umbrellas=sample(1:k,k)
Heads=sample(1:k,k)
m[i]=sum(Umbrellas==Heads)
}
m[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using R and that you are pretty new to it.

You missed the opening curly bracket after `function(k)` and the closing bracket at the end of the function as well. Also, you wrote the code as if you wanted to return only `m[i]` (the `i`-th element of `m`), but I guess you are more interested in the number of correct "person-coat-matches" per simulation.

```
Umbrella <- function(k){
  m = rep(0, 10000)
  for(i in 1:10000){
    umbrellas <- sample(1:k, k)       
    heads <- sample(1:k, k)
    m[i] <- sum(umbrellas == heads)
  }
  return(m)
}
```

note: you are doing 10.000 simulations, so `m` will be a vector with 10.000 values between zero and `k`.

Comment: Having ran this as a function, it does return a large vector of 10000 which maxes out and doesn't print all of, so how would I go about getting it to return a single value of correct matches?

Comment: @GeorgiaDickinson . I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Are you looking for the average of the m values? Or maybe a sum?

Comment: I am looking to find the probability that umbrellas=heads